# How do I return a specific SOAP response from an ASP.Net site?

Tags: c#, .net, soap

An external development partner has a service that will post a SOAP request to one of our services. The format of their request is fixed (by them).

We are required to respond with a SOAP message of a fixed format (fixed by them again).

I have created a Generic Handler in ASP.Net that successfully receives their request (which we parse manually and process).

However, they want a response that looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 01 Apr 2010 09:30:25 GMT
Server: Jetty/5.1.4 (Windows XP/5.1 x86 java/1.5.0_15
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=soaptestserver; type="text/xml"; start="<theenvelope>"
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 796
Connection: close

--soaptestserver
Content-ID: <theenvelope>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 442

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAPENV="
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"><SOAPENV:
Body><ns1:processResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:TripFlow" SOAPENV:
encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><message
href="cid:thecontentmessage"/></ns1:processResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAPENV:
Envelope>
--soaptestserver
Content-ID: <thecontentmessage>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 65

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><STATUSLVL>00</STATUSLVL>
--soaptestserver--
```

I have been so sheltered from raw SOAP by using .Net Webservices / WCF for years, that I have no clue about how to go about making a response like this.

What should I do?

Comment: I am not adding anything helpful here, so I apologize in advance. I am curious as to what the point of using SOAP is if they are intent on fixed requests/responses? Are they not able to just handle generic SOAP messages?

Comment: I'm curious about that too Quintin. Sadly they are in France, we are in New Zealand, and being time-zone separated by 12 hours is not helping things. Basically I want to set up our server as a test to respond exactly the way they specify, to rule out something we're doing wrong on our side.

Comment: Can they at least provide you with a WSDL/XSD ?? If so, you could pretty easily create a WCF service to handle such SOAP requests....

Comment: Well, I just assumed they couldn't provide a WSDL or XSD, but since there doesn't seem to be an easy answer to my question, then I think I will double check that with them. Hand writing the SOAP messages is just annoying..

Comment: Philosophically, they undermine the very idea of SOAP and go down one layer. Means you have to do the same if you want to respond. In a way, they want to exchange "arbitrary" strings in a client-server scenario. Have you considered setting up a simple server yourself where you have more control, parse the incoming request and feed them the desired string, using System.Net.Sockets or a component like the nsoftware IPDaemon Component, or (maybe even more easy) Kodart XF.Server?

Comment: @ScottFerguson, did ever had solution. I have same issue. If you can post it

Comment: Sorry @Milind, I have no idea now. That was 7 years ago! Best of luck.